# Jade/Pug iteration over data from server is massively over counted

Tags: json, node.js, loops, pug

I'm trying to iterate over a json array of 3 objects in Jade in order to populate some html (3 is arbitrary, I have one user with 380+).

**Instead of 3 divs, I'm getting about 5,000+. How do I iterate over this object from my Node.js sever so it will render properly in Jade/Pug?** My guess is that, instead of giving me the length of the array (3), it's giving me the length of the json string that makes that array which is over 5,000.

My server is sending this:

```
res.render('yourUploads', {fromServer:JSON.stringify(rows[0])});
```

`rows[0]` is the results from a mysql database query, 3 results.

```
    script.
        var data = !{fromServer};
        console.log(data); //prints "(3) [Object, Object, Object]"
        console.log(data.length); //prints "3"

    mixin posMixin(uploadData)
        div #{uploadData}

body

    div Welcome to your awesome uploads page
    div(onclick="window.location='/createNewUpload'") go to your awesome Create New Upload page

    - for (i = 0; i < fromServer.length; ++i) { //fromServer.length is about 5,000?
        +posMixin("whateverItTakesToGetThisToWork") //puts 5,000 divs into the dom!!!
    - }
```

As you might have guessed, I'm not exactly sure of what to put in place of `"whateverItTakesToGetThisToWork"`, but I wouldn't be surprised if it became rather obvious after I figure out what's wrong with this `fromServer` object. I had thought it would be `fromSever[i]` but that produces output so large it crashes my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Because you serielize the data using JSON.stringify, now the fromServer is a string, and maybe you cannot use the JSON methods in pug, just don't use JSON.stringify, pass the data directly.

Comment: That would work, but defeats the entire sever-side rendering that I'm going for. Plus, it would be a ton more work than just getting this iterator to behave.

Comment: @GlenPierce I updated my answer, the problem maybe JSON.stringify